# How to extract triples using Stanford CoreNLP package in java?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, triples

I want a code snippet which would take input a sentence or set of sentences and output or extract the triples(Subject,Predicate and Object) using Stanford CoreNLP package in java

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for OpenIE triples, or more structured relation triples (e.g., for things like `per:city_of_birth`)? For the former, the OpenIE system is likely what you're looking for: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/openie.html. Copying from the example there:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.RelationTriple;
import edu.stanford.nlp.simple.*;

/**
 * A demo illustrating how to call the OpenIE system programmatically.
 */
public class OpenIEDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create a CoreNLP document
    Document doc = new Document("Obama was born in Hawaii. He is our president.");

    // Iterate over the sentences in the document
    for (Sentence sent : doc.sentences()) {
      // Iterate over the triples in the sentence
      for (RelationTriple triple : sent.openieTriples()) {
        // Print the triple
        System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
            triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.objectLemmaGloss());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, using the Annotators API:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ie.util.RelationTriple;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.NaturalLogicAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * A demo illustrating how to call the OpenIE system programmatically.
 */
public class OpenIEDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Create the Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // Annotate an example document.
    Annotation doc = new Annotation("Obama was born in Hawaii. He is our president.");
    pipeline.annotate(doc);

    // Loop over sentences in the document
    for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      // Get the OpenIE triples for the sentence
      Collection<RelationTriple> triples = sentence.get(NaturalLogicAnnotations.RelationTriplesAnnotation.class);
      // Print the triples
      for (RelationTriple triple : triples) {
        System.out.println(triple.confidence + "\t" +
            triple.subjectLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.relationLemmaGloss() + "\t" +
            triple.objectLemmaGloss());
      }
    }
  }
}
```